# OpenGL main loop drawing huge vector of points

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

I have a MFC application which main draw loop has to draw a set of huge points. Right now, this is done as follows:

```
void CmodguiView::OnDraw(CDC* /*pDC*/) {

  wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_hRC);

  // Clear color and depth buffer bits
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  const std::vector<DensePoint> *pts;
  pts = getPts();

  if (pts) {
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (auto &&pt : *pts) {
        glColor3ub(pt.r, pt.g, pt.b);
        glVertex3f(pt.x, pt.y, pt.z);
    }
    glEnd();


    SwapBuffers(m_hDC);
  }

}
```

How do I optimize this? Can I avoid the `for` loop?
Would it be possible, for instance, to rotate the points directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottleneck are the countless calls of glVertex. This is called immediate mode, is denoted by glBegin…glEnd block and it has been deprecated for well over 10 years. Also immediate mode got obsolete with the introduction of vertex arrays over 15 years ago. So don't use it.

Instead you should use vertex arrays. You may combine them with buffer objects to further improve performance.

Anyway, assuming `DensePoint` is written as

```
struct DensePoint {
    GLubyte r,g,b;
    GLfloat x,y,z;
};
```

You can replace the glBegin…glEnd block with

```
std::vector<DensePoint> const * const pts = getPts();
if(pts) {
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glColorPointer (3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                    sizeof(DensePoint), &((*pts)[0].r));
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,
                    sizeof(DensePoint), &((*pts)[0].x));

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, pts->size());
}
```

Note that this still uses the old OpenGL-1.1 fixed function pipeline and points data stays in CPU/system memory, so this is will get not as much throughput as modern VBO based drawing operations. Also with modern OpenGL you get freely defined vertex attributes through shaders. But it's easy enough to go there starting from the code above.

Comment: thanks for the update. By the way, supposing I want to only draw 90% of those points. would it be possible to do womething like `glColorPointer (3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 10*sizeof(DensePoint), &((*pts)[0].r));`

Comment: @manatttta: Yes, you can abuse the stride parameter to skip some of the vertex attribute tuples. And you have to do it for *every* attribute then. However be aware that you have to reduce the value of the `count` parameter to `glDrawArrays` accordingly. In the long run, if you want to draw only a subset of the points it's advisable that you create an index array, populate it accordingly and draw using `glDrawElements`.